# Netlify breaks after adding netlify.toml file

Tags: netlify, vuepress

We are running a quite simple setup where we have a Vuepress project that is built using `yarn build` which relates to `vuepress build`. It all worked pretty great so far (first time netlify user)

We now wanted an environment variable in production builds.
To do so, I added a `netlify.toml` that looks like the following:

```
[context.production]
  environment = { NODE_ENV = "production" }
```

I do not know why, but suddenly the build on the main branch (which is our production build) breaks because yarn cannot find the `vuepress` command anymore.

This worked fine before the introduction of the netlify.toml (and still works fine for non-production branches)

The build log looks like:

```
3:04:22 PM: $ yarn docs:build
3:04:22 PM: yarn run v1.22.10
3:04:22 PM: $ vuepress build docs --clean-cache --clean-temp
3:04:22 PM: /bin/sh: 1: vuepress: not found
3:04:22 PM: error Command failed with exit code 127.
3:04:22 PM: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue on Netlify when people want to use `NODE_ENV` to make decisions for their builds with custom build scripts, etc.

By default the build bots on [Netlify set `NODE_ENV` to `development`](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/#node-js-environment), so yarn will install the dev dependencies.

If `vuepress` is in your `devDependencies`, yarn will ignore them when Netlify runs the yarn install automatically. There are a [couple work arounds](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1830).

- use: `NODE_ENV=development yarn install && yarn docs:build`
- use: `yarn add vuepress && yarn docs:build`
- remove the env variable setting if you don't need it. If you need to know if it is a production build, you can always use `CONTEXT` which is set by Netlify on a production build.

There are some other options, but I'll leave it here for brevity.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I couldn't find the `CONTEXT` variable you're referring to online. Is there some documentation around that?

Comment: `process.env.CONTEXT` is here: https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/#build-metadata